# How to build multiple segments sequence in GA api

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to get analytics data from GA api for segment sequence `sessions::sequence::ga:eventCategory=@EXAMPLE_EVENT_CATEGORY;ga:eventAction=@EXAMPLE_EVENT_ACTION;->>ga:eventCategory=@EXAMPLE_EVENT_CATEGORY2;ga:eventAction=@EXAMPLE_EVENT_ACTION2`

There is no documentation about filtering data from segment sequences. I think I have to use `Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SegmentSequenceStep` or/and `Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SequenceSegment` objects. Problem is that I have no idea where(how) to use it. I've tried to follow docs from here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#multiple_segments

```
protected function buildSimpleSegment($segmentName, $dimension, $dimensionFilterExpression) {
        // Create Dimension Filter.
        $dimensionFilter = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SegmentDimensionFilter();
        $dimensionFilter->setDimensionName($dimension);
        $dimensionFilter->setOperator("EXACT");
        $dimensionFilter->setExpressions(array($dimensionFilterExpression));

        // Create Segment Filter Clause.
        $segmentFilterClause = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SegmentFilterClause();
        $segmentFilterClause->setDimensionFilter($dimensionFilter);

        // Create the Or Filters for Segment.
        $orFiltersForSegment = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_OrFiltersForSegment();
        $orFiltersForSegment->setSegmentFilterClauses(array($segmentFilterClause));

        // Create the Simple Segment.
        $simpleSegment = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SimpleSegment();
        $simpleSegment->setOrFiltersForSegment(array($orFiltersForSegment));

        // Create the Segment Filters.
        $segmentFilter = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SegmentFilter();
        $segmentFilter->setSimpleSegment($simpleSegment);

        // Create the Segment Definition.
        $segmentDefinition = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_SegmentDefinition();
        $segmentDefinition->setSegmentFilters(array($segmentFilter));

        // Create the Dynamic Segment.
        $dynamicSegment = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DynamicSegment();
        $dynamicSegment->setSessionSegment($segmentDefinition);
        $dynamicSegment->setName($segmentName);

        // Create the Segments object.
        $segment = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Segment();
        $segment->setDynamicSegment($dynamicSegment);

        return $segment;
    }

function getReport() {
        $stats = [
            'ga_profile_from_search_page' => [
                'metric' => 'ga:uniquePageviews',
                'dimension' => 'ga:pagePath',
                'filter' => 'ga:pagePath=PATH_FILTER’,
                'startOffset' => '30 days ago',
                'segment' => 'sessions::sequence::ga:eventCategory=@EXAMPLE_EVENT_CATEGORY;ga:eventAction=@EXAMPLE_EVENT_ACTION;->>ga:EXAMPLE_EVENT_CATEGORY2=@Profile;ga:eventAction=@EXAMPLE_EVENT_ACTION2’
            ],
        ];

        foreach ($stats as $key => $stat) {

            // Create the DateRange object.
            $dateRange = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
            $dateRange->setStartDate(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stat['startOffset'])));
            $dateRange->setEndDate(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now')));

            // Create the Metrics object.
            $metric = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
            $metric->setExpression($stat['metric']);

            //Create the Dimensions object.
            $dimension = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
            $dimension->setName($stat['dimension']);

            // Create the segment dimension.
            $segmentDimensions = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
            $segmentDimensions->setName("ga:segment");

            // Specifying multiple segments
            $segmentFilter1 = $this->buildSimpleSegment("Search segment", "ga:eventCategory", "EXAMPLE_EVENT_CATEGORY");
            $segmentFilter2 = $this->buildSimpleSegment("Visit profile after search segment", "ga:eventAction", "EXAMPLE_EVENT_ACTION");
            $segmentFilter3 = $this->buildSimpleSegment("Profile page view segment", "ga:eventCategory", "EXAMPLE_EVENT_CATEGORY2");
            $segmentFilter4 = $this->buildSimpleSegment("Visit profile segment", "ga:eventAction", "EXAMPLE_EVENT_ACTION2”);


            // Create the ReportRequest object.
            $request = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
            $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
            $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
            $request->setMetrics(array($metric));

            $request->setFiltersExpression($stat['filter']);
            $request->setSegments(array($segmentFilter1, $segmentFilter2, $segmentFilter3, $segmentFilter4));
            $request->setDimensions(array($dimension, $segmentDimensions));

            $body = new \Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
            $body->setReportRequests(array($request));

            $response = $this->analytics->reports->batchGet($body);

            $this->printResults($key, $response);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I've been struggling with same problem for couple days, it's nightmare to use an api with no documentation. But I think I sorted it out, it gives me same results from analytics interface.

**Instead of** setting multiple `segments` to the `request`

`$request->setSegments(array($segmentFilter1, $segmentFilter2, $segmentFilter3, $segmentFilter4));`

**Do this**

Combine several `SegmentFilter`s at this line

`$segmentDefinition->setSegmentFilters(array($segmentFilter1, $segmentFilter2));`

and give just one `segment` to the `request`

`$request->setSegments(array($segment));`

with your current `buildSimpleSegment()` method this won't work so you need to change it and return `segmentFilter` then combine them in the `getReport()`

Hope it helps